# How do I set a variable in my SSIS package to a line in a text file?

Tags: sql-server-2008, visual-studio-2008, ssis

I am creating an SSIS package (using VS 2008) that will run various stored procedures, create files and place them where they can be uploaded into another system.  The package will run monthly and, since it will create around 9 files each time it is run, I would like to have the package take the previous month's files and archive them.  Also, these files will have names that will include the date they were run.  Since I will have no control on the running of these files, I cannot assume that they will run on the same day each month.

I thought the best way to do this would be to create a variable called lastrundate populate it with data from a text file that updates with the last run date everytime the package it run.  The problem is that I cannot figure out how to set the value of my user variable to the information in the text file.

Also, I should note that I have to use C#, as the set up for Visual Studio will not allow me to change the language to VB, and I have never worked with C#, so I am at a total disadvantage.

Comment: Until you click `Edit Script...`, you should be able to switch from the default language `Microsoft Visual C# 2008` to `Microsoft Visual Basic 2008.` Either way, I would not advocate taking the route you have described. If I were to restate the problem, you are looking for a mechanism to archive (move) previously created files where the filename has a date/timestamp embedded in it. Would that be accurate or do you *reallly* want to know how to assign a variable based on line N of a file?

Comment: Yes, that would be accurate. I was thinking that the easiest way to do this would to use a variable to determine the file name of the previously created file. How would you do that?  Also, thanks for the tip, I had been trying to change the language after I clicked on edit script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're archiving the files each time the process runs, you might consider starting the procedure by looping through the files in the 'default' directory, moving them to a date(date/time)-named 'archive' directory (with naming based on the date/time the package is run).

This approach means you don't need to parse the date out of the file name, but if some of the files will be archived and others will be re-used, it may not actually meet your needs.

Comment: that's part of the issue.  I have some files in the directory that are being used.  I'm sure that there is a better way to do this.

Comment: Another similar approach would be to *copy* the files to the archive directory instead of moving them, then update the process to overwrite the existing files (as appropriate).  This would allow you to re-use existing files as needed while still creating a full set of archive files.